# Scala: Implicit Conversion via a method (e.g. toString)

Tags: scala, view, implicit

In Scala, I'd like to do:

```
class Identifier(val str: String) {
    override def toString(): String = str
}

class Variable(t: Type, name: Identifier, mutable: Boolean) {
    override def toString(): String = name
}
```

But I can't because Scala won't implicitly convert `name` in `Variable#toString()`'s definition to a String. Is there a way this can be achieved ?

To be clear: I don't want to define an additional method like:

```
object Identifier {
    implicit def idToString(x: Identifier): String = x.str
}
```

I'd like the `toString()` method to be called to do the conversion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try putting an explicit `toString()` call after calling name in `Variables` toString method like so:

```
override def toString() = name.toString()
```

Here you will explicitly call the method converting `Variable` to a string, thus telling the compiler exactly what you want.

.. Unless you really require the method to be implicit...

Comment: I'd like the method to be implicit. It's more a question of curiosity as to what can be done than of practical matter.

Comment: If you _require_ an implicit conversion you need to bring it into scope somehow. An alternative to the object-way you wrote is to create a method inside the Variable class telling the compiler how to go from an `Identifier` to a `String`. Could look something like: `implicit def identifierToString(i : Identifier) = t.toString()`. I doubt there are any other solutions, but I could be wrong.

Comment: What you propose is in fact equivalent (and less general) than what I wrote in my question (putting the implicit method in the Identifier object). It's less general because if it is in the object, I can use implicit conversion everywhere, not only in the Variable class. Assuming of course that I want the implicit conversion to be visible everywhere.

Comment: Indeed it is. But it is an alternative and it saves you a couple lines of code. But I must admit I fail to see another way to do it. Implicits are just pieces of code working for you behind the curtains. As all other code implicits needs to be in scope. Perhaps there is a smarter way of doing it but I fail to see it :-)

Comment: I suppose it's not doable then. A shame, it would really be handy being able to pass any type when a string is required.

Comment: What's wrong with `implicit any2String(a: Any): String = a.toString`?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want 'odd' ways of doing this then you can use **member import**

```
class Variable(t: Type, name: Identifier, mutable: Boolean) {
  import name.{toString => toStr}
  override def toString(): String = toStr
}
```

you cannot do `import name.toString` as this gets hidden by all other `toString`s methods in `Any` etc

Answer (score 0):

```
override def toString(): String = name.toString
```

is not terribly taxing on the fingers